# Script to generate new machine-id on startup

Tags: boot, scripts, xubuntu, startup

I have to clone 600 hdd's equiped with Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and one of the issues i have is that the clones also copy informations like UUID's and machine-id's, which as you understand can be a littel bit troublesome.

After scooping around a colleague of mine came up with this:

```
cd /tmp 
vi change_mac_id
```

---

```
#!/bin/sh    
 if [ -f /etc/machine-id  ]; then    
   rm /etc/machine-id && \    
   systemd-machine-id-setup    
   echo "Changed !!"    
 fi
```

---

So, my question is: Can i make a script, that runs when the OS boots, checks the machine-id and IF it's the same with the machine-id from the original machine then generate a new one?

Comment: Have you ever heard about `cloud-init`? If not, read about it.

Answer (score 0):

To run your script at boot, you can put following in the /etc/crontab

```
@reboot root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
```